# Python Make string json loadable

Tags: python, json

I have this string:

```
> x.data
u'{u"orderNumber": u"69898327728", u"resultingTrades": []}'
```

How can I convert it to `json`? This doesn't work:

```
> import json
> json.dumps(x.data)
'"{u\\"orderNumber\\": u\\"69898327728\\", u\\"resultingTrades\\": []}"'
```

It just creates a long string. I need to convert it to json so that later I can do `json.loads` and access the keys in the dict, like this:

```
y = json.loads(x.data)["orderNumber"]
```

Comment: What you started with is a Python *repr* string. You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert it to a dictionary directly. You don't need to go through JSON at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see with your string is that it contains the python `u""` format for keys.

Now, if you trust your string and you know it will remain in that format, you can use `eval(x.data)` to get back a dictionary, but eval is very dangerous.

```
json.loads(json.dumps(eval(a)))
```

If I were you, I'd put more effort into making sure you get a better string to handle, if that is within your power.

If not, you can try removing the quotes and `u` manually.

```
data = x.data.replace('u"', "")
data = data.replace('"', "")
json.loads(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: If given a chance to use ``eval`` or ``ast.literal_eval``, I'd go with the latter. It seems a tad safer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the data to `dict`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = u'{u"orderNumber": u"69898327728", u"resultingTrades": []}'
>>> d = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> d['orderNumber']
u'69898327728'
```

Then you can use `dumps` and `loads` normally:

```
>>> import json
>>> ext = json.dumps(d)
>>> ext
'{"orderNumber": "69898327728", "resultingTrades": []}'
>>> json.loads(ext)['orderNumber']
u'69898327728'
```